# Mutual Authentication with SSL

Tags: web-services, ssl, apache-axis, mutual-authentication

I was trying to connect to a web service through rmi using a stub. It requires SSL handshake prior to connection. So for the certificate, I went to the webservice url, exported the certificate to a .cer file and imported the certificate in my keystore as

```
keystore -importcert -alias alias -keystore keystore.jks -file certificate.cer
```

and the certificate was imported and then later I added this same certificate to my truststore residing in : path-to-jre/lib/security/cacerts 
Also the webservice requires username and password to be passed while invoking which have been setup using :

```
 ((javax.xml.rpc.Stub) proxy)._setProperty(org.apache.axis.client.Stub.USERNAME_PROPERTY,
        "username");
((javax.xml.rpc.Stub) proxy)._setProperty(org.apache.axis.client.Stub.PASSWORD_PROPERTY,
        "password"));
```

I'm setting the keystore as : 
path-to-keystore/keystore.jks
and path of truststore:
path-to-jre/lib/security/cacerts

Also I'm using this code to set the keystore and trustore before invoking the call:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:/FAST/JDK64/LINKS/JDK8/bin/abc.jks");
                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStrore",
                        "C:/FAST/JDK64/LINKS/JDK8/jre/lib/security/cacerts");
                //"C:/FAST/JDK64/LINKS/JDK8/jre/lib/security/cacerts"
                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "changeit");
                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
```

When the handshake is initiated  I get the following stacktrace :

```
{http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
at org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.create(JSSESocketFactory.java:186)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)
at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)
at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
at com.good.gc10.GCSoapBindingStub.getUser(GCSoapBindingStub.java:6590)
at com.good.gc10.GcServerProxy.getUser(GcServerProxy.java:343)
```

Comment: You should have imported into the truststore, not the keystore. And you have both `keysore.jks` and `abc.jks`. Sort that out. There is no [tag:rmi] here.

Comment: Pardon me for the mistake but that keystore.jks is actually abc.jks only and I did import the certificate.cer file to truststore sitting in  path-to-jre/lib/security/cacerts